# Moveit_assistant just can't define a new pose?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use moveit_assistant to generate the configuration file, I just cant drag to define new pose ?
As the picture shown below, and I can't use the interactive marker to drag the model in rviz to set the goal eitheer?
Is there some thing wrong with my urdf file?[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348419/moveit_assistant-just-can%27t-define-a-new-pose?/) by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2020-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-05**:\

> As the picture shown below

there is no image shown.

In fact, you couldn't attach one, as you didn't have sufficient karma.

I've rectified that, so please attach it again.

**Comment by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) on 2020-04-05**:
I 'm very glad to receive your answer, I've attach it.  The reason I can't move it is that I didn't know the safe controller in URDF file can cause this problem. My  URDF file is directly generate from sw2urdf. Still thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-06**:
Is that a KUKA robot?

**Comment by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) on 2020-04-06**:
Yep, It is a KUKA robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-06**:
Which one?

**Comment by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) on 2020-04-06**:
KR60-3，you can check it here.
https://www.robots.com/robots/kuka-kr-60-3

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-06**:
I was just curious whether there would already be support for that robot in [ros-industrial/kuka_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental). Seems there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see. The reason I can't move it is that
If the “soft_lower_limit” and the “soft_upper_limit” in the safety_controller are set to 0.0, your joint will be unable to move. MoveIt! relies on you to specify the correct robot model.

---

Originally posted by [Jiawenxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53229/jiawenxing/) with karma: 86 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0